# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'host'

Tags: python

I am trying to raise an exception and provide the hostname on which host it errors

I have tried this code

```
class ZabbixNonZero(Exception):
  """ Raise when output value is failed """
def __init__(self, value):
        super(ZabbixNonZero, self).__init__(value)
        self.value = value
def __str__(self):
       return repr(self.value)
Metric = [
    ZabbixMetric(host='xxx.xx.x.xx', key='test[cpu_usage]',value=2),
    ZabbixMetric(host='xx.xx.xx', key='zabbixsender', value="Everything ok")
]
print Metric
result = ZabbixSender(use_config=True).send(Metric)
host='xx.xx.xx'
try:
  print(result)
except Exception as err:
  raise ZabbixNonZero(err)
if result.failed != 0:
  raise ZabbixNonZero('Failed to send data to host'.format(Metric.host))
```

My output is

```
This is Metric output [{"host": "xx.xx.xx", "value": "2", "key": "test[cpu_usage]"}, {"host": "xxx.xx.xx", "value": "Everything ok", "key": "zabbixsender"}]
 This is result output {"failed": 1, "chunk": 1, "total": 2, "processed": 1, "time": "0.000237"}
```

I am trying to raise an exception on which host it is failed.

I except the output should be Failed to send data to host xxx.xx.xx

Can you please help how to retrieve the host value in exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate the list to get the hosts.

**Ex:**

```
raise ZabbixNonZero('Failed to send data to host {}'.format(", ".join(i["host"] for i in Metric)))
```

Comment: I am getting this error raise ZabbixNonZero('Failed to send data to host'.format(", ".join(i["host"] for i in Metric)))
TypeError: 'ZabbixMetric' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: try replacing `i["host"]` with  `i.host `

Comment: [{"host": "xx.xx.x", "value": "2", "key": "test[cpu_usage]"}, {"host": "xx.xx.x.xxx", "value": "Everything ok", "key": "zabbixsender"}]
{"failed": 1, "chunk": 1, "total": 2, "processed": 1, "time": "0.000149"}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zabbixsender.py", line 29, in <module>
    raise ZabbixNonZero('Failed to send data to host'.format(", ".join(i.host for i in Metric)))
__main__.ZabbixNonZero: Failed to send data to host

Comment: It is not iterating the data in Metrics, can you please help?